# Deriving the Lagrangian in constraint motion - where do Multipliers come from?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, constrained-dynamics, variational-calculus

Say we have $N$ bodies satisfying the following constraint: $h(\vec x_1 , ... ,\vec x_N)=0$. I'm aware of the fact that we then have to introduce the Lagrangian multipliers, but I want to see how we can get there. How do we construct the Lagrangian and why do we construct it that way, the multipliers must come from somewhere. The (incomplete) method I've come to after reading a mechanics book and some googling was the following:

*Let's ignore the constraint for a bit:*

We know that the Lagrangian for $N$ bodies (a simple "version"), not considering the constraint, is $$L= \sum_1^N (\frac12m_i \dot { x_i}^2 -  V_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)) $$
and we're also aware of Hamilton's principle: the evolution of the system will be the one that makes the action $S=\int_{a}^{b}Ldt $ stationary. So suppose the virtual displacements $δ\vec x_i$, then by expanding the Lagrangian and integrating we get $$δS= -\int_{a}^{b} (\sum_1^N m\ddot{\vec x_i} +\vec\nabla_iV)δ\vec x_i  dt \space \space (1)$$ Where $δS$ is the change in action, not considering terms of second order or higher.
Which we want equal to 0, if we are to find the evolution of the system.

Without constraints, that's fairly easy, because the fact that $(1)$ must be 0 for all virtual displacements means that $(\sum_1^N m\ddot{x_i} +\vec\nabla_iV)$ must be zero, which is in fact Newton's second Law.

Now let's consider the constraint:

Now the $δ\vec x_i$ are not random, they must satisfy $h$, that is $h(\vec x_1 +d\vec x_1 , ... , \vec x_N + δ\vec x_N)=0$. Lets do a Taylor expansion for that: $$ 0=h(\vec x_1 +d\vec x_1 , ... , \vec x_N + δ\vec x_N)= h(\vec x_1 , ... ,\vec x_N) + \sum_1^Nδ\vec x_i\vec\nabla_ih.$$

So we see that the $δ\vec x_i$ must be such that $$ \sum_1^Nδ\vec x_i\vec\nabla_ih=0 \space \space (2)$$

Let's write $$ δ\vec x = (δ\vec x_1,...,δ\vec x_N) , \vec\nabla h=(\vec\nabla_1 h,...,\vec\nabla_Nh), \vec N=(m_1 \vec x_1 + \vec\nabla_1V,..., m_N \vec x_N + \vec\nabla_NV)$$ And define an inner product $\bullet$ in this 3N-dimensional space in the obvious way.
Concluding we have the following:$$ \begin{cases}  \int_{a}^{b} \vec N \bullet δ\vec x  dt=0   \\ δ\vec x \bullet \vec\nabla h=0 \end{cases} $$

And this gives us a nice idea, which I can't complete rigorously. The fact that an inner product is 0 means that the elements are perpendicular to each other.We see from the second equation that $δ\vec x \bot \vec\nabla h$ and from the first one, if we were to ignore the inegral it would mean that $\vec N\bot δ\vec x$

So that could only mean that $\vec N$ and $\vec\nabla h$ are parallel, that is $\vec N= λ(t) \vec\nabla h$, which is excactly what we have with Lagrangian multipliers: it tells us that we need only substract these terms from our initial Lagrangian and we're good to go.

However we have the integral in front of the inner product. So is my method correct up to a point? If so, what more am I missing?

Comment: Consider the $\mathbb{R}^3$ canonical basis. $\vec{e}_1\perp \vec{e}_2$ and $\vec{e}_3\perp \vec{e}_1$- But in general it is not true that $\vec{e}_2\parallel \vec{e}_3$. So, for it to be true you have to show that $\vec{N} = \alpha\vec{\nabla}h + \beta\delta\vec{x}$. Since the integral is 0 for inifitely many paths from $a$ to $b$, then the integrand must be 0.

Comment: We have that the first equation holds for ALL $δx$ such that $δ\vec x \bot \vec\nabla h$. So they must be parallel.